# Encrypting in JS and decrypting in Java - errors

Tags: angularjs, encryption, cryptography, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a usecase where I need to encrypt in JS and decrypt in Java. I've tried 2 approaches:

1. Based on the [this library in github](https://github.com/mpetersen/aes-example)

For this case, I'm getting a javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded error.

2. Code written by referring various sources. 
   For encryption:

   ```
       var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
       var salt_hex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(salt);
       var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
       var iv_hex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(iv);
       var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(secret, salt, {
           keySize : 256 / 32,
           iterations : 1
       });

       var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key, { iv : iv });
   ```

   I pass the 'salt', 'iv' and 'encrypted' to the JS code. Here I decrypt it using

   ```
   SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
   plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(msg), "UTF-8");
   ```

In this case, I'm getting a java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size in this case.

My setup is :

1. The JS side is written in an AngularJS service
2. The server java code is invoked through an adapter in MobileFirst Server

Any pointers on where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Artjom B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816580/artjom-b), thanks for the answer. I had already performed all the steps you mentioned without any luck.

The code in option 2 is working now. One possible reason for it to work is a machine restart. Else can't think of any other changes that could have affected it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no problem in the code you provided:

- Check that PBKDF2 produces the same key on both ends.
- Check that you correctly decode hex to bytes and vice versa (where it is needed).
- Check that you installed the Unlimited Strength policy for AES-256 (currently [v7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) and [v8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html)). AES-256 is not enabled by default when using JCE, because of US military export restrictions.